# What is supposed to happen when a procedure's argument is given multiple values when it expects one value only?

Tags: scheme

`(+ (values 1) (values 2))` returns `3`. What is `(+ 1 (values 2 3))` supposed to return? In R7RS-small, is the second value in a `(values ...)` automatically ignored when only one value is needed? In Guile 3.0.7, `(+ 1 (values 2 3))` returns `3`, but it gives an error in MIT Scheme 11.2 and Chibi 0.10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(+ (values 1) (values 2))` is fine, and the result should be `3`. But it is not the case that unneeded values are automatically ignored in a `values` expression; in fact the behavior of `(+ 1 (values 2 3))` is unspecified in both R6RS and R7RS Scheme.

From the entry for `values` from [R6RS 11.15](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.15) [emphasis mine]:

> Delivers all of its arguments to its continuation....
>
> The continuations of all non-final expressions within a sequence of
> expressions, such as in `lambda`, `begin`, `let`, `let*`, `letrec`,
> `letrec*`, `let-values`, `let*-values`, `case`, and `cond` forms,
> usually take an arbitrary number of values.
>
> Except for these and the continuations created by `call-with-values`,
> `let-values`, and `let*-values`, ***continuations implicitly accepting a
> single value, such as the continuations of <operator> and
> <operand>s of procedure calls or the <test> expressions in
> conditionals, take exactly one value. The effect of passing an
> inappropriate number of values to such a continuation is undefined.***

R7RS has similar language in 6.10:

> The effect of passing no values or more than one value to continuations that were not created in one of these ways is unspecified.

The reason that `(+ (values 1) (values 2))` is ok is that continuations of operands in procedure calls take exactly one value. `(values 1)` and `(values 2)` each provide exactly one value for their respective continuations.

`call-with-values` is meant for connecting producers of multiple values with procedures which consume those values. The first argument to `call-with-values` should be a procedure which takes no arguments and produces values to be consumed. The second argument should be a procedure which accepts the number of values produced by the first procedure:

```
> (call-with-values (lambda () (values 2 3))
    (lambda (x y) (+ 1 x y)))
6
```

Note that the above use of `call-with-values` requires the consumer to accept the number of values produced by the producer since Scheme requires that implementations raise an error when a procedure does not accept the number of arguments passed to it:

```
> (call-with-values (lambda () (values 2 3 4))
    (lambda (x y) (+ 1 x y)))

Exception: incorrect argument count in call (call-with-values (lambda () (values 2 3 4)) (lambda (x y) (+ 1 x y)))
```

If it is desirable for extra arguments to be ignored, the consumer must be designed towards that goal. Here the consumer is designed to ignore all but its first argument:

```
> (call-with-values (lambda () (values 2 3 4))
    (lambda (x . xs) (+ 1 x)))
3
```